# Mapping Mongodb ObjectId to Mysql ID Field

Tags: mysql, django, mongodb

I have an mongodb based application which use 12 byte objectid as primary key and as user id, and I have another Django app using Mysql, and need to inherits the user id generated from mongodb (inherit means not create new id but just store id which come from mongodb, and use it as a foreign key anywhere possible).

What's the best solution of,

1. what data type to be used to express Mongo Object Id in mysql? binary(12)?
2. considering using Django, any extra plugin needed for using binary(12)?
3. or any solution different from the above?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you simply cast objectid to string.

Comment: Yah it could be the last solution for me cos the length of string seems too long, it's 24 chars.. so I'm seeking for a better solution than that first.

Comment: Binary seems like a good fit. Or, stop using the built-in ObjectId from MongoDb and use something more friendly to the rest of your solution.

Answer (score 9):

I have been using both `BINARY(12)` and `VARCHAR(24)` to store MongoDB's ObjectIds in MySQL. `BINARY(12)` uses less disk space, but you need to use `HEX()` to work with it as a string.